# Datatable.select get rows dulicate

Tags: c#, datatable

I have datatable like this:

```
Code    Class
A       Math
A       History
B       Math
B       Math
```

I wanna rows which have same Code value but Class is not same. Something Expected:

```
A       math
A       History
```

I had tried Datatable.select and Group By , but it Dont work! Help me.

Comment: Which programming language? Can you show the non-working examples of the code?

Comment: iam using C#. Thank for your watching.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way of doing this via LINQ should be something like:

```
dataTable.Distinct()
         .GroupBy(x => x.Code)
         .Where(gr => gr.Count() > 1)
         .SelectMany(gr=> gr);
```